# How to get the checked state of Switch from menu items

Tags: android, android-layout, menuitem

I have added the switch in Menu items and trying to access its checked state.But i am not able to access its checked state.Can any one help me out.

this is my menu_crime.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/crime_toggle"
    android:title="Crime"
    android:enabled="true"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/toolbar_crime_toggle" />

</menu>
```

this is my toolbar_crime_toggle.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/crime_switch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/SCBSwitch"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Crime"
    android:switchPadding="50dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried to access its checked state in onCreat() like this

```
 mSwitchShowSecure = (SwitchCompat) menu.findItem(R.id.crime_toggle).getActionView().findViewById(R.id.crime_switch);
    mSwitchShowSecure.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Log.d("ischecked", String.valueOf(isChecked));
        }
    });
```

Comment: how are you trying to access it? Share some more code

Comment: i want to access it in my activity

Comment: show the code that is not working

Comment: i have edited the question please check

Answer (score 2):

You can find checked state of SwitchCompat anywhere using **switchCompat.isChecked()** method.

If it gives **true** it means switch is **on** otherwise **off**.